# Unable to create a new instance eventlistener in Omnifaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, seam, omnifaces

I am trying to use `Converters Features` of `Omnifaces`. My development environment as below:

```
-primefaces 3.5
-jsf 2.0
-spring 3.5
-Jboss Seam 2.3
```

This environment is ok and there is no configuration error. When I add new `omnifaces-1.6.3.jar` to `WEB-INF\lib`, Unable to deployed the application..

```
....
14:14:59,563 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
14:14:59,565 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 98 ms
14:14:59,595 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/cycfm'
14:15:00,215 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationExcept
ion: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/java/JBoss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/cycfm.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.6.3.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener': java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.subscribeToEvent(Application.java:1812) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.subscribeToEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:709) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.util.Events.subscribeToEvent(Events.java:180) [omnifaces-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener.<init>(InvokeActionEventListener.java:65) [omnifaces-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 14 more

14:15:00,227 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cycfm]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to liste
ner instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/java/JBoss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/cycfm.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.6.3.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener': java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
...
```

Is there configuration in `web.xml` or `faces-config.xml` to use `Ominifaces`. I think, there is no problem in my page and backing bean.

mypage.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p>
        <b>Last selected item:</b> <h:outputText id="selected_item" value="#{ChartBean.selectedEntity.value}" />
    </p>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="iterator" value="Items with iterator: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="iterator" value="#{ChartBean.selectedEntity}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Choose item" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{ChartBean.exampleEntities}" var="entity" itemLabel="#{entity.value}" itemValue="#{entity}" />
            <f:ajax render="selected_item" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p>
        <b>Selected items</b>:
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty ChartBean.selectedEntity}">
            <ui:repeat value="#{ChartBean.selectedEntity}" var="entity" varStatus="loop">
                #{entity.value}#{loop.last ? '' : ', '}
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:fragment>
        <h:outputText value="[no selection made]" rendered="#{empty ChartBean.selected}"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <b>Choose a city, then press Select</b>:
        <p:pickList value="#{ChartBean.dualListModel}" var="entity" itemValue="#{entity}" itemLabel="#{entity.value}">
            <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListIndexConverter" list="#{ChartBean.exampleEntities}" />
        </p:pickList>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h:commandButton value="Select">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </p>            
</h:form>
```

ChartBean.java

```
@Name("ChartBean")
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {
    private List<ExampleEntity> exampleEntities;
    private DualListModel<ExampleEntity> dualListModel;
    private ExampleEntity selectedEntity;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        exampleEntities = new ArrayList<ExampleEntity>();
        exampleEntities.add(new ExampleEntity(1L, "Amsterdam"));
        exampleEntities.add(new ExampleEntity(2L, "Frankfurt"));
        exampleEntities.add(new ExampleEntity(3L, "London"));

        dualListModel = new DualListModel<ExampleEntity>(exampleEntities, new ArrayList<ExampleEntity>());        
    }

    public List<ExampleEntity> getExampleEntities() {
        return exampleEntities;
    }

    public ExampleEntity getSelectedEntity() {
        return selectedEntity;
    }

    public void setSelectedEntity(ExampleEntity selectedEntity) {
        this.selectedEntity = selectedEntity;
    }

    public DualListModel<ExampleEntity> getDualListModel() {
        return dualListModel;
    }

    public void setDualListModel(DualListModel<ExampleEntity> dualListModel) {
        this.dualListModel = dualListModel;
    }

    public List<ExampleEntity> getSelectedModel() {
        return dualListModel.getTarget();
    }   
}
```

**Update :**

I got one point, when I use `omnifaces-1.4.1.jar` there is no deployment error. But I cannot use `omnifaces.ListIndexConverter`.

**Update :** New Jar file `omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar`

```
16:54:31,484 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
16:54:31,484 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 93 ms
16:54:31,843 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/cycfm'
16:54:32,919 INFO  [org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) init: org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplicationFactory@1c121b6
16:54:33,515 INFO  [org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) set: com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl@a95d88, false
16:54:33,515 INFO  [org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication] (MSC service thread 1-1) init: com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl@a95d88
16:54:33,780 INFO  [org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) get: org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication@d9fc12
16:54:33,780 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationExcept
ion: 
  Source Document: vfs:/D:/java/JBoss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/cycfm.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener': java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.subscribeToEvent(Application.java:1812) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.subscribeToEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:709) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.util.Events.subscribeToEvent(Events.java:180) [omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT-20131126]
    at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener.<init>(InvokeActionEventListener.java:65) [omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT-20131126]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 14 more

16:54:33,796 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cycfm]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialized event to liste
ner instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/D:/java/JBoss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/cycfm.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener': java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/D:/java/JBoss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/cycfm.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener': java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:132) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.subscribeToEvent(Application.java:1812) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.subscribeToEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:709) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at org.omnifaces.util.Events.subscribeToEvent(Events.java:180) [omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT-20131126]
    at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.InvokeActionEventListener.<init>(InvokeActionEventListener.java:65) [omnifaces-1.7-20131127.003718-16.jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT-20131126]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 14 more

16:54:33,812 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
16:54:33,812 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/cycfm] startup failed due to previous errors
16:54:33,827 SEVERE [javax.faces] (MSC service thread 1-1) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFa
ctory. Attempting to find backup.
16:54:33,827 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime: java.
lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1011) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
```

Comment: Thank you for reporting. What if you remove Seam (just to see if it deploys)? Problem suggests that `OmniApplicationFactory` failed to do its job, but I can't figure any possible cause. Perhaps Seam also provided its own `ApplicationFactory` which did things differently. I'll have to look in Seam source code.

Comment: I made a theoretical fix, can you please give [today's 1.7 snapshot](http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.7-SNAPSHOT/omnifaces-1.7-20131126.131330-13.jar) a try?

Comment: @BalusC, Thank for your providing. I already try 1.7. The problem is same. I will test my application without using `Seam 2.3`. I will replay to you.

Comment: Hm OK, are you using Spring-Faces or Spring-WebFlow? They also come with their own `ApplicationFactory`.

Comment: @BalusC, I don't use it. I just use `Spring` for db transaction control.

Comment: Okay. Stacktrace tells that you're using JBoss-supplied JSF 2.1 implementation Mojarra 2.1.7. Are you absolutely positive that you didn't supply your own copy of JSF 2.0 API/impl along with the webapp, hereby possibly polluting the classpath? Your question namely explicitly mentions "JSF 2.0" which is somewhat suspicious.

Comment: I added logger lines to current snapshot which should probably provide more insight. Can you please give it a try? https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=284

Comment: @BalusC, Thank again. Problem is the same. I update new stack trace.

Comment: Aren't you seeing logger lines from `org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory` during startup?

Comment: @BalusC, I get this line. I update my stack trace.

Comment: I dropped jboss-el.jar+jboss-seam.jar from Seam 2.3 in my test project and I get the same logger lines and yet it deploys fine :( I even tried specifically JBoss AS 7.1.1 to exclude its bundled and slight modified Mojarra from causing it, but it even deploys fine. I don't see other way to naildown this than asking you to create and send me a minimalistic WAR file reproducing the problem. Note that I didn't install Spring.